# How to use XPath to find the closest ancestor in a ancestor-or-self nodelist

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a structure with recurring elements like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <a>
    </a>
  </b>
  <a>
    <b>
       <a>
         <c att="val" />
       </a>
    </b>
  </a>
</a>
```

Asuming the c-node is the $currentNode, when I use XPath

```
<xsl:value-of select="($currentNode/ancestor-or-self::a)" />
```

I get an unordered list of nodes matching the expression. What I need is to always get the node closest up the tree, as in deepest in the branches or the highest @level.

I cannot use XPath 2 max-function like this unfortunately:

```
<xsl:value-of select="($currentNode/ancestor-or-self::a)[max(@level)]" />
```

Notice that the closest a-node not always is exactly above the context, just somewhere up there...

Any suggestions appreciated!

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 9):

I think you get an ordered set of nodes, from parent to ancestor.

Try `$currentNode/ancestor-or-self::a[1]` to get parent of c att="val".

Comment: I tried this approach. Listing the first, the second etc. And I find the closest node is on the second place... :(

Comment: Are you sure $currentNode = element c ?

Comment: Yes, but maybe I get this effect because my actual XPath is "ancestor-or-self::*/a" and not just a ?? (I simplified it for clearing things up)

Comment: @Alex, this answer is correct -- just try and see for yourself. +1.